# EventFiringWebDriver does not notify of events

Tags: c#, selenium

OS: Windows 10 
Selenium Version: 2.53.0
Browser: Chrome 
Browser Version: 50.0.2661.102m

Expected Behavior - Should get a call back on the code example below

Actual Behavior - None of the event handlers are called when clicking on link elements that navigate.

Steps to reproduce - Create a selenium project in Visual Studio, navigate to your favorite site, call this code after the webdriver is returned from the gotoURL method call.

StartWebDriver below, opens a new WD instance and navigates to the url returning the Webdriver. We see the new url open up in Chrome. Next we call the HookEventFiringWebDriver... and are never notifiied.

```
    var wd = StartWebDriver(url);
    wd.HookEventFiringWebDriver(changedURL => {});
```

Here's the helper class which hooks the event, I've tried different methods for hooking but none work.

```
public static void HookEventFiringWebDriver(this IWebDriver wd, Action<string> NavigatedToURL) {
    var ed = new EventFiringWebDriver(wd);
    ed.ElementClicked += new EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs>((o, e) => {
        Debugger.Break();
    });
    ed.Navigated += (driver, ea) =>
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        if (NavigatedToURL != null) NavigatedToURL(ea.Url);
    };
    ed.ElementClicked += (driver, ea) =>
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        if(NavigatedToURL !=null) NavigatedToURL(ea.Element.Text);
    };
    ed.Navigating += (driver, ea)=>{
        Debugger.Break();
        if (NavigatedToURL != null) NavigatedToURL(ea.Url);
    } ;
    ed.ExceptionThrown += (driver, ea) =>
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    };
} -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone wanting a functional way to hook up an 
EventFiringWebDriver using C# with optional call backs...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows for events to be posted back to the user from the browser
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="wd">The WebDriver to hook into</param>
    /// <param name="Error">Any Exceptions if thrown</param>
    /// <param name="Navigating">On Navigation start</param>
    /// <param name="NavigatedToURL">On Navigation complete</param>
    /// <param name="Clicked">On web element clicked</param>
    /// <param name="HookedDriver">The Hooked driver</param>
    /// <returns>The Hooked driver</returns>
    public static IWebDriver HookEventFiringWebDriver(this IWebDriver wd,
        Action<WebDriverExceptionEventArgs> Error = null,
        Action<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs> Navigating = null,
        Action<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs> NavigatedToURL = null,
        Action<WebElementEventArgs> Clicked = null,
        Action<IWebDriver> HookedDriver = null)
    {
        var ed = new EventFiringWebDriver(wd);
        ed.ElementClicked += new EventHandler<WebElementEventArgs>((o, ea) =>
        {
            if (Clicked != null) Clicked(ea);
        });
        ed.Navigated += (driver, ea) =>
        {
            if (NavigatedToURL != null) NavigatedToURL(ea);
        };

        ed.Navigating += (driver, ea) =>
        {
            if (NavigatedToURL != null) NavigatedToURL(ea);
        };
        ed.ExceptionThrown += (driver, ea) =>
        {
            if (Error != null) Error(ea);
        };
        if (HookedDriver != null) HookedDriver(ed);
        return ed;
    }
```

And here's how to use it.

```
        CurrentWebDriver.HookEventFiringWebDriver(
            error => { 
                //process errors here 
            },
            navigating => {
               //browser is navigating
            },
            navigated => { 
              //browser has navigated 
            },
            clicked => { 

             //element was clicked
            }, 
            wd => {
                wd.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `EventFiringWebDriver` class is an extended class designed to intercepts the calls to a `WebDriver`instance. So to notify the events, you need to call the methods from the `EventFiringWebDriver` instance.

Here is an example:

```
var driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver());

driver.Navigated += new EventHandler<WebDriverNavigationEventArgs>((obj, ea)=>{
    Debugger.Break();
});

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

Comment: My example above does the exact same thing at your example.  However, you are using Firefox, I was using Chrome.  I wonder if the reason your example works is due to the FireFoxDriver?

Comment: It works with Chrome the exact same way. Note that your example doesn't include the calls to the browser (`.GoToUrl`, `.Click`, ...). You are probably calling the methods on the `WebDriver` instance instead of the `EventFiringWebDriver` instance. You can check it with `driver.GetType().FullName`.

Comment: Ok that's the problem I'm navigating the original web driver and not the event driver.  Let me give that a shot.

Answer (score 0):

One other note: The EventFiringWebDriver also (in C#) contains a private reference to the EventFiringWebElement (EFWE). If you pass it into another method as a IWebElement it will simply hide the ability to get the Wrapped driver.  Here's how to expose it....

```
public static IWebElement ScrollIntoView(this IWebElement ele){
        var rele = ((IWrapsElement)ele).WrappedElement as RemoteWebElement;
        var wd = rele.WrappedDriver;
        var action = new Actions(wd);
        action.MoveToElement(ele);
        action.Perform();
        return ele;
    }
```